# twitter login - xlm version =1.0 encoding = "UTF-8" error 415 Callback URL not approved for this client application

Tags: twitter, react-native

I am trying to use a social auth (twitter into firebase) on android and I get the error above .

As I understand it there is nothing wrong with my code , just some error in twitter developer platform, I ll post both of them just to be sure

```
 _twitterSignIn = async () => {
    context = this

    const twitterAccessToken = await getTwitterAccessToken();
    const twitterAccessTokenSecret = await getTwitterAccessTokenSecret();
    console.log("twitterAccessToken: " + twitterAccessToken + ", twitterAccessTokenSecret: " + twitterAccessTokenSecret);

    auth({ consumerKey: Constants.TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY, consumerSecret: Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, accessToken: twitterAccessToken, accessTokenSecret: twitterAccessTokenSecret }
        , "myapp://twitter", { accessType: "write", forSignIn: false, forceLogin: false, screenName: '' }).then(({ accessToken, accessTokenSecret, id, name }) => {
            // context.loginLoader({loading:false})
            context.props.updateLoader({ loading: false })
            AsyncStorage.setItem(TWITTER_AUTH_TOKEN, accessToken)
            AsyncStorage.setItem(TWITTER_AUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, accessTokenSecret)
            setTwitterConfig();
        }).catch(console.error);
}
```

[image]

PS: I also tryed adding twittersdk:// to callback url ,still doesnt work